# c: using copyfile.h for Mac

Tags: c, macos, file-copying

I am playing with the Mac OSX `copyfile` function to move a file using C. Header file found [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-391.2.3/darwin/copyfile.h)

```
int copyfile(const char *from, const char *to, copyfile_state_t state, copyfile_flags_t flags);
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <copyfile.h>

    int main() {
    int success;
    const char* from = "hello.text";
    const char* to = "/toGo/hello.txt";
    copyfile_state_t state = copyfile_init();
    copyfile_flags_t flags = "COPYFILE_MOVE";

    success = copyfile(from, to, state, flags);
    printf ("%d\n", success);
    exit(0);
}
```

I added `copyfile_init()` function to initialize the state. And I get compiling issues now but I think I am getting in the right direction.

```
$ gcc move.c
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_copyfile_init", referenced from:
  _main in ccXJr5oN.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Based on what I've seen online this is a linking issue. So I added the link tag but it's not finding the file, and this header is supposed to be in OSX source.

```
$ gcc move.c -lcopyfile
ld: library not found for -lcopyfile
```

Comment: There is no `copyfile_init()` function. I think you were looking for `copyfile_state_alloc()`. Type `man 3 copyfile` at your command line for a description of this call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPYFILE_MOVE` is a flag constant. It doesn't belong in a string. To actually transfer the file's data, you'll also need to set the `COPYFILE_DATA` flag.

Also, you can leave out the `state` parameter. <s>(You didn't bother to initialize it anyway.)</s> Just pass `NULL` instead.

This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <copyfile.h>

int main() {
  int success;
  const char* from = "hello.text";
  const char* to = "/toGo/hello.txt";
  copyfile_flags_t flags = COPYFILE_MOVE | COPYFILE_DATA;
  success = copyfile(from, to, NULL, flags);
  printf ("%d\n", success);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had passed NULL before and got errors. Anyway, I copy pasted your code directly and I get a print out of -1.

Comment: It's working fine for me. Make sure the filesystem permissions allow you to read the source file and create a new file in the destination folder.

Comment: rw on both of the files

Comment: Is there anyway to get more information on the error I'm getting. This -1 is unhelpful.

Comment: I am able to move a folder using recursive. But not a single file.